# @Transactional is giving error on Grails method

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-2.0

I am using Grails 2.1.1. In a controller I have a method on top I have used `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` as follows:

```
@Transactional
def saveItem() {
    ...
}
```

Then it is giving this error in the console: `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` and showing only some code in the browser instead of form element. But if I remove `@Transactional` from on top of the method the view is rendering fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: As I remember all actions in controller are transactional by default.

Comment: @Koloritnij - I don't believe controllers are transactional, where as services are.

Comment: I know so. I have worked with grails 2.4.2. there save and update are transactional.

Answer (score 0):

The support for `@Transactional` annotation was introduced in Grails 2.3.x so it's not working in your case and your Grails version is older.

As a workaround, either you can move all your controller business logic code to a Grails service (which are transactional by default) or wrap your controller code inside `withTransaction` method.

```
@Transactional
def saveItem() {
    AnyDomain.withTransaction {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: "The support for @Transactional annotation was introduced in Grails 2.3.x" - I think the original question is related to `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`, not `grails.transaction.Transactional`.

Comment: but I need to update 3 domain in this method. otherwise roleback. How to do it with withTransaction ?!!